# How can I get the result of my work in a Task

Tags: c#, task

I need to do a work in a Task (infinite loop for monitoring) but how can I get the result of this work?

My logic to do this stuff i wrong? This is a scope problem I think.

There is an example simplified:
The variable is "first" and I want "edit"

```
namespace my{
    public class Program{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            Logic p = new Logic();
            Task t = new Task(p.process);
            t.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(p.getVar());// result="first"  
        }
    }

    public class Logic{
        public string test = "first";
        public void process(){
            while(true){
                //If condition here
                this.test = "edit";
            }
        }

        public String getVar(){
            return this.test;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you're starting the task, but not waiting for it to complete. Your description doesn't match the code though - in this case it would make sense to wait for the task to complete, but not in the case you describe where it's an infinite loop. At what point would that infinite loop provide results?

Comment: First you didn't really explain what you want. What kind of result do you expect out of an infinite loop? A notification perhaps? The first succesful result? Second, tasks aren't threads. You don't need `.Start` to start them. Just use `Task.Run(someMethod)`. You can await for it to finish with `await Task.Run(...)` and assign any results with `var result=await Task.Run(...)`

Comment: @Steve what are you trying to do? Poll a service and record every result? Or poll it and record the first failure? Do you want the loop to continue after the first failure?

Comment: This is for network monitoring so it's possible to obtain frames at irregular intervals in the loop. And theses trames are store in a list, the same way as my String var in my example. That's why I can't wait the end of the Task. Indeed I would like to continue to monitor after the first failure?

Comment: maybe what you are looking for is async/await. Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: @Steve you are still describing what you think the solution will look like. What do you mean network monitoring? What kind of calls are you making? Are there *asynchronous* versions of those calls? You may not need to use `Task.Run` to start the calls, just wait for them to complete

Comment: @Steve as for the notifications, what are you going to do with them? Do you simply want to report progress? In this case you can use the `IProgress< T>` interface. Store them? Use `ConcurrentQueue`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using custom `event`. In your case it can be something like:

```
public event Action<string> OnValueChanged;
```

Then attach to it

```
p.OnValueChanged += (newValue) => Console.WriteLine(newValue);
```

And do not forget to fire it

```
this.test = "edit";
OnValueChanged?.Invoke(this.test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tasks aren't threads, they don't need a `.Start` call to start them. All examples and tutorials show the use of `Task.Run` or `Task.StartNew` for a reason - tasks are a *promise* that a function will execute at some point in the future and produce a result. They will run on threads pulled from a ThreadPool when a Task Scheduler decides they should. Creating cold tasks and calling `.Start` doesn't guarantee they will start, it simply makes the code a lot more difficult to read.

In the simplest case, polling eg a remote HTTP endpoint could be as simple as :

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var client=new HttpClient(serverUrl);
    while(true)
    {
        var response=await client.GetAsync(relativeServiceUrl);
        if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //That was an error, do something with it
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

There's no need to start a new Task because `GetAsync` is asynchronous. WCF and ADO.NET also provide asynchronous execution methods.

If there's no asynchronous method to call, or if we need to perform some heavey work before the async call, we can use Task.Run to start a method in parallel and await for it to finish:

```
public bool CheckThatService(string serviceUrl)
{
    ....
}

public static async Task Main()
{
    var url="...";
    //...
    while(true)
    {
        var ok=Task.Run(()=>CheckThatService(url));
        if(!ok)
        {
            //That was an error, do something with it
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

What if we want to test multiple systems in parallel? We can start multiple tasks in parallel, await all of them to complete and check their results:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var urls=new[]{"...","..."};
    //...
    while(true)
    {
        var tasks=urls.Select(url=>Task.Run(()=>CheckThatService(url));
        var responses=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        foreach(var response in responses)
        {
           ///Check the value, due something
        }
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

`Task.WhenAll` returns an array with the results in the order the tasks were created. This allows checking the index to find the original URL. A better idea would be to return the result and url together, eg using tuples :

```
public static (bool ok,string url) CheckThatService(string serviceUrl)
{
    ....
    return (true,url);
}
```

The code wouldn't change a lot:

```
var tasks=urls.Select(url=>Task.Run(()=>CheckThatService(url));
var responses=await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
foreach(var response in responses.Where(resp=>!resp.ok))
{
    ///Check the value, due something
}
```

What if we wanted to store the results from all the calls? We can't use a List or Queue because they aren't thread safe. We can use a [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
ConcurrentQueue<string> _results=new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

public static (bool ok,string url) CheckThatService(string serviceUrl)
{
    ....
    _results.Enqueue(someresult);
    return (true,url);
}
```

If we want to report progress regularly we can use `IProgress<T>` as shown in [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/).

We could put all the monitoring code in a separate method/class that accepts an `IProgress< T>` parameter with a progress object that can report success, error messages and the URL that caused them, eg :

```
class MonitorDTO
{
    public string Url{get;set;}
    public bool Success{get;set;}
    public string Message{get;set;}        

    public MonitorDTO(string ulr,bool success,string msg)
    {
     //...
    }
}

class MyMonitor
{
    string[] _urls=url;
    public MyMonitor(string[] urls)
    {
      _urls=url;
    }   

    public Task Run(IProgress<MonitorDTO> progress)
    {
      while(true)
      {
         var ok=Task.Run(()=>CheckThatService(url));
         if(!ok)
         {
            _progress.Report(new MonitorDTO(ok,url,"some message");
         }
         await Task.Delay(1000);
      }
    }
}
```

This class could be used in this way:

```
public static async Task Maim()
{
    var ulrs=new[]{....};
    var monitor=new MyMonitor(urls);
    var progress=new Progress<MonitorDTO>(pg=>{
         Console.WriteLine($"{pg.Success} for {pg.Url}: {pg.Message}");
    });
    await monitor.Run(progress);
}
```

[Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) shows how to use the CancellationTokenSource to implement another important part of a monitoring class - cancelling it. The monitoring method could check the status of a cancellation token periodically and stop monitoring when it's raised:

```
    public Task Run(IProgress<MonitorDTO> progress,CancellationToken ct)
    {
      while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        //...
      }
    }

public static async Task Maim()
{
    var ulrs=new[]{....};
    var monitor=new MyMonitor(urls);
    var progress=new Progress<MonitorDTO>(pg=>{
         Console.WriteLine($"{pg.Success} for {pg.Url}: {pg.Message}");
    });
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    //Not awaiting yet!
    var monitorTask=monitor.Run(progress,cts.Token);
    //Keep running until the first keypress
    Console.ReadKey();
    //Cancel and wait for the monitoring class to gracefully stop
    cts.Cancel();        
    await monitorTask;
```

In this case the loop will exit when the CancellationToken is raised. By not awaiting on `MyMonitor.Run()` we can keep working on the main thread until an event occurs that signals monitoring should stop.

Answer (score -1):

The `getVar` method is executed before the `process` method.
Make sure that you wait until your task is finished before you call the `getVar` method.

```
Logic p = new Logic();
Task t = new Task(p.process);
t.Start();
t.Wait(); // Add this line!
Console.WriteLine(p.getVar());
```

If you want to learn more about the `Wait` method, please check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: But the task in real app (not simplified example) is infinite loop so you will wait forever on `t.Wait()`

Comment: Too many mistakes and misunderstandings. Tasks aren't threads, they don't need an explicit `start`. `Task.Run` is enough. Blocking them with `.Wait()` or `.Result` essentially *negates* them. If you wait to await a task and retrieve its value use `await`

Comment: Creating instance of task instead of using `Task.Run` will use current TaskScheduler instead of default one. It is better to stick with `Task.Run`